# How is Model.get_or_insert() an ancestor transaction in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, bigtable

I don't understand how google app engine for python's `Model.get_or_insert(key_name, **kwds)` method works.

From my understanding, all datastore operations inside a transaction must be ancestor queries.  However, I don't see how the documentation for `Model.get_or_insert(key_name, **kwds)` is an ancestor query.  For the following example, since 'parent' is not specified in the arguments for the last line, wouldn't the result of `parent=kwds.get('parent')` in the second line be `None`, thus negating the query as an ancestor query?:

```
def txn(key_name, **kwds):
    entity = Story.get_by_key_name(key_name, parent=kwds.get('parent')) # parent is not defined?
    if entity is None:
        entity = Story(key_name=key_name, **kwds)
        entity.put()
    return entity

def get_or_insert(key_name, **kwargs):
    return db.run_in_transaction(txn, key_name, **kwargs)

get_or_insert('some key', title="The Three Little Pigs")  # no parent specified
```

([link to documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert))

I'm not trying to split hairs here, I'm just having trouble understanding how to properly use transactions in my own application and was looking to this documentation to augment my understanding.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need ancestor queries to guarantee atomicity in a transaction that involves multiple entities.  All the entities in the transaction need to share the same ancestor.  Model.get_or_insert() only retrieves one entity, which obviously shares the same ancestor with itself.

Key paths/ancestors determine how data is stored in the App Engine datastore.  Entities with a common ancestor are stored on the same database shard, making it easier to implement atomic transactions without synchronizing between shards.

If you're using the HRD, which you probably are at this point, Cross Group transactions are available too, although I'm not too certain on how they work behind the scenes.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Cross_Group_Transactions

Comment: Pass xg=True to the transaction() function. Then you can touch up to 5 entity groups in the transaction callback instead of being limited to a single one.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a None ancestor as long as you have only one object in the transaction.
Trying to create/get more than one entity will throw an exception.